# Jquery select href build

Tags: jquery

Fairly new to jquery so I might be making a simple mistake but I just cant seem to find it. At the moment I have a select drop down that I want to send the user to the url that is built from the option they choose. At the moment I have this for my jquery:

```
    $('#sizeSelect').change(function () {
       var singleValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
       var singleUrl = '/products/length' + '~' + escape(singleValue);
       alert(escape(singleValue));
       alert(singleUrl);
       alert('/products/length' + '~' + escape(singleValue));
    window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('href', 'singleUrl');
});
```

I have my alerts in there for me to see how everything was being put together. When I get to my actual window.location the url that is built has [object%20Object] in it . So any help would much appreciated to a a somewhat new jquery user.

Comment: did you know you can grab the selected value of a drop down in jQuery without digging into the options? in your case, just call `$(this).val();` inside the change function.

Comment: thanks I did not no that, thats why i love stackoverflow someone always teaches me something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not send your users directly to the `singleUrl` variable?

```
window.location = singleUrl;
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do on the last line:

`$(this).find('option:selected')` will return the selected `li` element, but it will be returned as an object. You will need to use `.val()` as you did earlier to return the value of the `li`.

The second part, `.attr('href', 'singleUrl')` will attempt to find the `href` attribute of the `li` element (which doesn't exist) and set its value to `singleUrl`, which really won't do anything for you.

Comment: That worked exactly how it should of. I was just try to set the href , when you were asking what I was doing there but it seems like I was going about that all wrong. Thanks for your help, very new to this all

Comment: Glad it worked! Keep on going, it keeps getting more intuitive and fun the more you work with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`singleUrl` is a variable, not a string.  Change to:

```
window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('href', singleUrl);
```